# Comments form showing blank comments even when database is empty, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building a comments section on my blog, and so far I have it working to the point where I can successfully submit comments and have them appear on my page.

However, there is always a blank comment on the page whether I have 10 comments or the database is empty.

```
*** views/artist/lyrics/show.html.erb ***

<%= form_for(@lyric.comments.build, url: artist_album_lyric_comments_path(@artist, @album, @lyric)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :content %>
  <%= f.submit "comment" %>
<% end %>
<% if @lyric.comments.any? %>
  <% @lyric.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <%= comment.username %>
    <%= comment.content %>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  No one has commented.
<% end %>


*** /controllers/users/comments_controller.rb ***

def create
  @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
  @comment.user_id = current_user.id
  @comment.username = current_user.username
  @comment.lyric_id = Lyric.friendly.find(params[:lyric_id]).id
  if @comment.save
    redirect_to (:back)
  else
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

The Comment model is nested and I think that has something to do with it. It's `Artist` => `Album` => `Lyric` => `Comment`

When I remove the Comment form from the page the blank comment disappears and the `<else>` statement runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed this line:

`<%= form_for(@lyric.comments.build, url: artist_album_lyric_comments_path(@artist, @album, @lyric)) do |f| %>`

to:

`<%= form_for(Comment.new, url: artist_album_lyric_comments_path(@artist, @album, @lyric)) do |f| %>`

It runs the else statement and gets rid of the new record on the page.

Answer (score 0):

In your `form_for` tag, you are building a `comment` on `@lyric`. I believe this is showing up when you are calling `@lyric.comments` immediately after. Try:

```
<% @lyric.comments[0..-2].each do |comment| %>
```

That will grab all the `comments` from the first to the second to last (basically all of them except the new one you just created).

Edit:

Also change `<% if @lyric.comments.any? %>`  to `<% if @lyric.comments.any? && !@lyric.comments[0].new_record? %>`

Comment: Yeah, that definitely gets rid of the blank Comment, but it doesn't allow the `<else>` statement to run.

Comment: Ok, then change `<% if @lyric.comments.any? %>` to `<% if @lyric.comments.any? && !@lyric.comments[0].new_record? %>`. That should tell you if the first record is a new record, then it shouldn't be considered.

Comment: Alternately, refactor to have "No one has commented." as your first block and change `<% if @lyric.comments.any? %>` to `<% if @lyric.comments[0].new_record? %>` - then put the comment rendering block in the else block.

Answer (score 0):

I used this on my code before. Try this:

```
<% @lyric.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <% next if comment.new_record? %>
    <%= comment.username %>
    <%= comment.content %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Similar to my code, but then the `else` statement will never run because there will always be a `comment`.

Comment: oh right. I just think this is easier to type and its very verbose on what it does. And for the problem of else not firing, I would suggest `<% if @lyric.comments.length > 1 %>`